# Can not add debian backports

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, deb

I am trying to install https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/debianstretch-nginx

However when I try to add: `deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main` and run `apt-get update` I get:

> NO_PUBKEY 8B48AD6246925553 NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010

I tried some of the solutions online like:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/274055 but they do not seem to work on my system (Raspberry PI Debian 9 stretch).

Comment: Did you try the solution you linked to, only with your missing keys (8B48AD6246925553 & 7638D0442B90D010)?

Comment: Yes but if I remember correctly I got a error saying that they keys could not be found or did not exists

Comment: The last one matches the fingerprint for "pub   rsa4096 2014-11-21 [SC] [expires: 2022-11-19]
      126C 0D24 BD8A 2942 CC7D  F8AC 7638 D044 2B90 D010
uid           [ unknown] Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (8/jessie) <ftpmaster@debian.org>"

Comment: Sorry I am not familiair with this, what should I try?

Comment: Fixed the problem

Comment: How? You could answer the question yourself, it might help others. I was guessing something involving apt-key or apt-secure, or MX Linux has a checkaptgpg package/script that adds missing keys

Comment: Added the answer

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by doing:

`sudo apt-get install dirmngr`

and then:

`sudo apt-key adv --recv-key 8B48AD6246925553 && sudo apt-key adv --recv-key 7638D0442B90D010`

Comment: you could have installed debian's debian-archive-keyring which would have added these keys and will keep them up to date. But of course that's still a chicken-and-egg problem (how to trust it's the right package initially?)